# Problem with Storybook integration with Tailwind CSS in a NextJS + TypeScript Project

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook

I was trying to integrate Storybook into my NextJS + Typescript Project which uses TailwindCSS 3. Also I'm using yarn workspaces for maintaining the mono-repo.

When I try to run storybook, I'm hitting this error every time and am unable to find a solution.

```
ModuleError: Module Error (from ../../node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Loading PostCSS "tailwindcss" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- /Users/codebuddy/Workspace/the-ageless-clinic/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js
- /Users/codebuddy/Workspace/the-ageless-clinic/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/codebuddy/Workspace/the-ageless-clinic/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/codebuddy/Workspace/the-ageless-clinic/node_modules/webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin.js
```

I have different solutions from GitHub and StackOverflow, but still giving this error.

Below is the configuration which might help in debugging,

tailwind.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  content: [path.join(__dirname, "./src/**/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)")],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

src/.storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-postcss",
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require("postcss"),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
};
```

dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.5",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.11",
    "@types/node": "17.0.35",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "typescript": "4.7.2",
    "webpack": "^5"
  }
```

Project Folder Structure
[image]